# Turning off debugging, NDEBUG

Tags: c++, assert

C++ Primer says that

> The behavior of assert depends on the status of a preprocessor variable named NDEBUG. We can "turn off" debugging by providing a `#define` to define
>   `NDEBUG`

It is my expectation that when define is provided, asserts won't be executed.

```
#define NDEBUG TRUE

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    assert(argc==0);  // checked

    return 0;
}
```

Why, in this example, is `assert` statement checked, when `NDEBUG` is defined? (Correct me if i am wrong, but it does not matter to what it is defined, right?)

When executed from command line, using the `-DNDEBUG` flag, all works as expected (`assert` is not executed)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`NDEBUG` only affects `assert` if you define it before including `<cassert>` (or `<assert.h>`; note that you can include these headers multiple times changing the behaviour of `assert` depending on `NDEBUG`).

You don't need to define it to any specific value, or any value at all:

```
// this is OK
#define NDEBUG
```